# Get loss values for each training instance - Keras

Tags: python, python-3.x, keras

I want to get loss values as model train with each instance.

```python
history = model.fit(..)
```

for example above code returns the loss values for each epoch not mini batch or instance.

what is the best way to do this? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 16):

There is exactly what you are looking for at the end of this official keras documentation page https://keras.io/callbacks/#callback

Here is the code to create a custom callback

```
class LossHistory(keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def on_train_begin(self, logs={}):
        self.losses = []

    def on_batch_end(self, batch, logs={}):
        self.losses.append(logs.get('loss'))

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(10, input_dim=784, kernel_initializer='uniform'))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='rmsprop')

history = LossHistory()
model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=128, epochs=20, verbose=0, callbacks=[history])

print(history.losses)
# outputs
'''
[0.66047596406559383, 0.3547245744908703, ..., 0.25953155204159617, 0.25901699725311789]
'''
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to get loss values for each batch, you might want to use call `model.train_on_batch` inside a generator. It's hard to provide a complete example without knowing your dataset, but you will have to break your dataset into batches and feed them one by one

```
def make_batches(...):
    ...

batches = make_batches(...)
batch_losses = [model.train_on_batch(x, y) for x, y in batches]
```

It's a bit more complicated with single instances. You can, of course, train on 1-sized batches, though it will most likely thrash your optimiser (by maximising gradient variance) and significantly degrade performance. Besides, since loss functions are evaluated outside of Python's domain, there is no direct way to hijack the computation without tinkering with C/C++ and CUDA sources. Even then, the backend itself evaluates the loss batch-wise (benefitting from highly vectorised matrix-operations), therefore you will severely degrade performance by forcing it to evaluate loss on each instance. Simply put, hacking the backend will only (probably) help you reduce GPU memory transfers (as compared to training on 1-sized batches from the Python interface). If you really want to get per-instance scores, I would recommend you to train on batches and evaluate on instances (this way you will avoid issues with high variance and reduce expensive gradient computations, since gradients are only estimated during training):

```
def make_batches(batchsize, x, y):
    ...


batchsize = n
batches = make_batches(n, ...)
batch_instances = [make_batches(1, x, y) for x, y in batches]
losses = [
    (model.train_on_batch(x, y), [model.test_on_batch(*inst) for inst in instances]) 
    for batch, instances in zip(batches, batch_instances)
]
```

Comment: I want the loss values after training model on each instance. So if I am correct you are suggesting I feed 1 instance at a time as a batch? I was wondering if there is a more efficient way to get the loss information.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to calculate the loss function between train expectations and predictions from train input. In the case of loss = mean_squared_error and three dimensional outputs (i.e. image width x height x channels):

```
model.fit(train_in,train_out,...)

pred = model.predict(train_in)
loss = np.add.reduce(np.square(test_out-pred),axis=(1,2,3)) # this computes the total squared error for each sample
loss = loss / ( pred.shape[1]*pred.shape[2]*pred.shape[3]) # this computes the mean over the sample entry 

np.savetxt("loss.txt",loss) # This line saves the data to file
```

Answer (score 0):

After combining resources from [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/2850) and [here](https://keunwoochoi.wordpress.com/2016/07/16/keras-callbacks/) I came up with the following code. Maybe it will help you. The idea is that you can override the `Callbacks` class from keras and then use the `on_batch_end` method to check the loss value from the `logs` that keras will supply automatically to that method.

Here is a working code of an NN with that particular function built in. Maybe you can start from here -

```python
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.callbacks import Callback

# fix random seed for reproducibility
seed = 155
np.random.seed(seed)

# load pima indians dataset

# download directly from website
dataset = pd.read_csv("https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/pima-indians-diabetes/pima-indians-diabetes.data", 
                      header=None).values
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(dataset[:,0:8], dataset[:,8], test_size=0.25, random_state=87)
class NBatchLogger(Callback):
    def __init__(self,display=100):
        '''
        display: Number of batches to wait before outputting loss
        '''
        self.seen = 0
        self.display = display

    def on_batch_end(self,batch,logs={}):
        self.seen += logs.get('size', 0)
        if self.seen % self.display == 0:
            print('\n{0}/{1} - Batch Loss: {2}'.format(self.seen,self.params['samples'],
                                                logs.get('loss')))


out_batch = NBatchLogger(display=1000)
np.random.seed(seed)
my_first_nn = Sequential() # create model
my_first_nn.add(Dense(5, input_dim=8, activation='relu')) # hidden layer
my_first_nn.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')) # output layer
my_first_nn.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

my_first_nn_fitted = my_first_nn.fit(X_train, Y_train, epochs=1000, verbose=0, batch_size=128,
                                     callbacks=[out_batch], initial_epoch=0)
```

Please let me know if you wanted to have something like this.

Comment: Callback interface does not seems to have a operation to get loss by each instance. `on_batch_end` only return loss at the end of each mini batch. What I want to do is get deeper and get loss after each training instance. Any suggestions?

Comment: Thanks @SRC. This works! I only need to set batch size to 1.

Comment: @e.hurrington you shouldn't do it. batchsize affects training performance badly (even if you don't consider training time), i.p. your model might fail to converge on 1-sized batches.

Comment: @SRC thanks. I do not mind the training time. But I need it to converge. I will look at some alternatives. Please share if you have any. Thanks again.

Comment: @e.hurrington I've given you an alternative in my edit.

Comment: Welcome. I am happy that it helped you. However, I agree with @EliKorvigo that using batch size = 1 can not only degrade the performance severely but may also prevent your model from converging. Remember, we are talking about VERY high dimensional optimization problem. So, if you want to have loss per mini batch (set the batch size to 64 or 128 which is small already) then use this method otherwise, I believe, EliKorvigo method is your only way. Anyway, I believe both the answers should give you good direction to follow. Thanks EliKorvigo I learnt also from your answer. Upvoting.