# How to get loss for each sample within a batch in keras?

Tags: keras

How can I get the loss for each sample within a batch? It seems that Keras does not provide any functions meeting the demand.

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48118111/get-loss-values-for-each-training-instance-keras) and answers

Answer (score 7):

Keras always computes losses per sample. It has to do so in order to calculate the loss values that will be used as the basis of back propagation. The values are not typically exposed to the user other than as their average per batch but they are calculated by the loss function and then averaged for display purposes.

A very simple example model:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.keras.backend as K
keras = tf.keras

model = keras.models.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Input(shape=(4,)),
    keras.layers.Dense(1)
])

def examine_loss(y_true, y_pred):
  result = keras.losses.mean_squared_error(y_true, y_pred)
  result = K.print_tensor(result, message='losses')
  return result

model.compile('adam', examine_loss)
model.summary()
```

If you execute the follow test code:

```
import numpy as np
X = np.random.rand(100, 4)

def test_fn(x):
  return x[0] * 0.2 + x[1] * 5.0 + x[2] * 0.3 + x[3] + 0.6

y = np.apply_along_axis(test_fn, 1, X)

model.fit(X[0:4], y[0:4])
```

You should seem something like the following:

```
losses [23.2873611 26.1659927 34.1300354 6.16115761]
```

(Numbers will differ since they depend on random initialisation).

This may interest you or not depending on what you want to do with the individual losses. That was not clear at all from the initial question.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response, and it interests me a lot. The question is, I define a custom loss function, and I want to get the loss for each sample, is it possible? And I train the model with train_on_batch.

Comment: 1) If you define a custom loss function you must calculate a loss per batch sample. You can then choose to average the batch loss yourself or follow the convention used by keras losses and return an individual loss per sample as we saw in the example above with ```mean_squared_error```.

Comment: 2) It is unclear to me what you mean by "I want to get the loss for each sample". Do you mean that you would like to track it has a metric per sample ? If so, you could create a custom metric that evaluates the per sample loss tensors and saves the output in the ```logs``` variable used by metrics.

Comment: 3) fit and fit_generator do invoke train_on_batch; it is unclear why you want to re-implement the fit method and what you are trying to achieve. It seems unrelated to the rest of the question since we have established that losses are calculated per sample.

Comment: Meta question: What is your end goal ? Are you trying to understand how losses are calculated in a NN ? The answer to that is that losses are calculated per sample while gradient updates are performed per mini batch given the average of the batch. Batch size itself is controllable and an hyper parameter of model training.

Comment: I understand what you mentioned in the meta question. Actually, I need the losses for each sample to do some calculations. The question is, Keras always returns the average of the losses for samples when the model is trained with train_on_batch. I expect that I can get the losses individually rather than a mean value.

Comment: @zhf061 is right. This method will return not the loss on each sample in the batch but only the loss on the total batch. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48118275/11764049) for a solution and an explanation of what you want to achieve

Answer (score 5):

I know this thread is a bit old, but I found a neat solution and maybe this helps someone:

```
import tensorflow as tf

# Suppose you have an already trained model
model = ...

loss = SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(reduction=tf.compat.v1.losses.Reduction.NONE) # The loss function is just an example, the reduction is the important one
model.compile(optimizer=model.optimizer, loss=loss) # keep your original optimizer

# And then you'll get each loss for each instance within a batch
model.evaluate(X,y, batch_size=128)
```

Comment: Can't edit it so, here it goes. `reduction` parameter indicates what to do with each loss value from the batch, default value usually sumes them, but depends on the context. Its type is tf.keras.losses.Reduction and [`here`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/Reduction) you can read other options.

Comment: Now if only there were a way to do it without having to own the model in the first place. I'm working on code that uses the loss from a model, but I want to minimize the constraints on how the original model is put together. Otherwise, the calling code is tightly coupled with my function, since they have to modify their loss to make it work with my code. It frustrates me that there isn't a method available in the Keras interface that provides this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think keras provides this feature, because the loss for each individual sample inside a batch is never calculated. I think the loss is only calculated for an average over the batch.

One very useless (and time consuming) workaround could be to iterate over the training data and train on single samples.

Correct me if it turns out I'm wrong.

Comment: Yeah you're right. I cannot find a way to get the loss for each sample.

Comment: The default loss function provided by keras return an array of loss values (1 per batch sample). This array is then averaged to provide the "loss" number that you tend to see. The loss per individual sample must always be calculated since that is required to calculate the gradients.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not just interested in getting the loss for each sample during training, then you can use the `evaluate` method:

```
# assume images is already defined (e.g. as a numpy array)
#        images.shape = (n_images, n_rows, n_cols, n_channels
n_images = images.shape[0]
loss = n_images*[None]

for i in range(n_images):

    # note I'll use the same input for x & y parameters which is the case for an autoencoder
    loss[i] = model.evaluate(x=images[i:i+1,:,:,:],
                             y=images[i:i+1,:,:,:],
                             batch_size=None,
                             verbose=1,
                             steps=1
                             )
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set the batch size equal to 1. And then write a custom Callback for model.evaluate to collect each loss on_test_batch_end.